# How to run state.highstate for a particular environment?

Tags: salt-stack

My environments structure in /etc/salt/master looks like this

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
  dev:
    - /srv/salt/dev
  stg:
    - /srv/salt/stg
  prod:
    - /srv/salt/prod
```

And my top.sls file is in /srv/salt

```
dev:
  'ip-10-1-1-28':
    - devtest

stg:
  'ip-10-1-1-252':
    - stgtest

prod:
  'ip-10-1-1-200':
    - prodtest
```

Now I want to run state.highstate for a particular environment, say 'stg'. I am looking for something like this,

```
salt '*' state.highstate env=stg
```

How do I achieve this? My requirement is that every time I run the command, I don't want minions in all the environments to run the SLS files. Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You have this capacity but the correct command is:

```
salt '*' state.highstate saltenv=stg
```

[Salt state documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.sls)

Comment: It didn't work for me. When I executed that command, i got the following error , ip-10-1-1-252:
----------
          ID: states
    Function: no.None
      Result: False
     Comment: No Top file or external nodes data matches found
     Started:
    Duration:
     Changes:

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     1 . I got this for both the minions

Comment: Please show your "pillar_roots" configuration. 2 top.sls files must be saltenv synced (top.sls for pillar and top.sls for states)

Comment: Can you please be more specific about pillar_roots? I didn't modify anything for pillar_roots configuration. I only modified file_roots in master configuration file which I showed in my post.

Comment: Do you have a top.sls file in /srv/pillar where all your env are set

Comment: Can you post stgtest file please ? Normaly you must have two top.sls files. One in srv/pillar and another for the state in /srv/salt

Comment: Even if the documentation says the opposite, the argument `saltenv` is still written `env` in salt 0.17.5 (Ubuntu 14.04)